# net 4.0 page validator undefined

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

Web form with .Net validators works perfectly on the development server.

On the production server, .Net seems to fail to generate client side script 'Page_ClientValidate' and browser throws 'Page_ClientValidate is undefined'

Can't seem to figure out what the issue is? Is there a setting in IIS or server level to fix the issue?

Please help, have been trying to resolve it for days with no luck.

```
function ValidateForm() {
    var validForm = true;
    Page_ClientValidate("formWrapperValidationGroup");
    validForm = validForm && Page_IsValid;
    if (validForm) { 
          $("#formWrapper .fieldSubmitButton input[type=submit]").css("display", "none"); 
          $("#formWrapper .fieldSubmitButton .fieldSubmitButtonStatus").css("display", "inline-block"); 
   }
    return validForm;
}
```

Comment: Can you show `Page_ClientValidate` related code? Try checking if it is a function using `typeof(Page_ClientValidate) === "function"`, and check if you have `RequiredFieldValidator` or any controls with `Validator` suffix which using `ControlToValidate` & `EnableClientScript`.

Comment: Why is .Net not generating the default JS Validation function. It works on my development server, just not working on the production.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#Form1').submit(function () {
    if (typeof (Page_ClientValidate) == 'function') {
        Page_ClientValidate();
    } else {
        $(this).valid();
    }
});
```

Comment: Tried the above. But it throws 'TypeError: $(...).valid is not a function'. Why is .Net not generating the default JS Validation function. It works on my development server, just not working on the production.

Comment: Please check your jquery path in production mode. !!

Comment: Thanks for helping out. Checked the Jquery path is it is correct. But noticed 'js.axd?path=%2fWebResource.axd' is showing 500 error? Could be related to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

js.axd?path=%2fWebResource.axd - Redirect rule caused an issue with resolving the js.axd file path. Fixed it b fixing the redirect rule.